# My array isn't adding objects

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I'm wondering why `myNumber` didn't get added to `myArray`. Sorry, if the answer is really obvious. I'm just stuck in this section in my Objective-C book about arrays.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 5];
        NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        [myArray addObject: myNumber];

        NSLog(@"%lu", [myArray count]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [myArray objectAtIndex: 0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2012-08-02 21:53:30.827 prog[1889:707] 0
2012-08-02 21:53:30.829 prog[1889:707] (null)
```

Comment: You can initialize an array with object (I believe it's called [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:myNumber,nil];
does it work then?

Comment: Also, place a breakpoint on the line trying to add the object, and make sure that myArray isn't nil there. it might not have been properly allocated for some reason. just thinkink out loud

Comment: The code you've given us here appears to be correct. Can you show us the actual code that's breaking?

Comment: What system are you compiling on? Please include version numbers of programs. The code, as you posted it, works fine on a Mac with Xcode 4.3.3.

Comment: Oh I actually just tried erasing myArray and declared another mutable array, and it worked. Thanks for the comments though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSNumber *myNumber2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[myArray addObject: myNumber2];

NSLog(@"%u", [myArray count]);
NSLog(@"%@", [myArray objectAtIndex: 0]);
```